# Host two Laravel Projects using same Database

Tags: mysql, database, hosting, laravel-5

I Have Created **two Laravel projects** using the **same database**. It works fine on my local host. Would like to know whether I can **host them as two web pages** using the same database. If Possible Please be kind enough to give me necessary hints.

I tried googling but wasn't much successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works locally, it should work on a remote server.  You should be able to configure Laravel to look for specific database prefixes, allowing you to have tables for two different Laravel installations in one database.

This page may help give you some background info: https://laravel.com/docs/master/database

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I Have already read the documentation. Couldn't find any thing related about hosting. Any way thank you.!!

Comment: What specific hosting information are you looking for.  It's a pretty broad topic.  If you go with something like HostGator or something else running cpanel, you will get an account with cpanel access, which you can then log into and set up your database and then upload your files via SFTP (or FTP).  You can then install subdomains or directories, with both laravel projects.  They can use the same database but have different views, etc.  That's basically all there is to a basic setup like that.

Comment: Thanks!! Thats what i was loking for!!